# azure websiteでサイトに接続できない

Tags: azure

WebMatrixでサイトを作成しているのですが作成したサイトを閲覧しようとするとこのような画面になり閲覧できません
[image]
ログインすればいいのでしょうが、どこからログインすればいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

画面上に小さく HTTP403 と書かれているのが重要です。これは一般的には「そのURLへのアクセスが認められていない」ということを広く意味します。ログインが必要というのは可能性の一つにすぎず、今回はおそらく違う理由でしょう。

「azure website 403」で検索してみたところ次の記事が見つかりました。

[[Windows Azure] Web Role 初回配置時にサイトにアクセスすると 403 Forbidden - Access Denied が表示される - Microsoft Azure サポート チーム サイト - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116051751/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dsazurejp/archive/2011/08/17/azure-403-forbidden-access-denied.aspx)

`index.html` や `default.html` といった既定のドキュメントが配置されていない時に403が表示されるようです。これらのファイルは配置されていますか？

Comment: 完全にそれでした！
解決しました。